# How to I create a new column in sql using conditional clause?

Tags: sql, database

This code worked until I introduced case clause. All I want to do it to make a new column whose value is 1 is prediciton >0 else O.

```
SELECT p.cohort_name, DATEPART(Month, date)as mm, AVG(prediction)
CASE WHEN ((p.prediction) < 0 THEN 1 else 0 END) as Z 
FROM
rates.rates_cohort_predictions p 
Group by 1,2
order by p.cohort_name, DATEPART(Month, date)
```

Comment: Seems like you need comma before CASE

Answer (score 0):

As [mvp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734130/mvp) stated, you are missing a select statement delimiter

This is the correct SQL statement

```
SELECT p.cohort_name, 
DATEPART(Month, date) AS mm, 
AVG(prediction), 
    CASE WHEN (
        (p.prediction) < 0 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS Z 
FROM rates.rates_cohort_predictions AS p 
GROUP BY 1,2 
ORDER BY p.cohort_name, DATEPART(Month, date)
```

Comment: SELECT p.cohort_name, 
DATEPART(Month, date) AS mm, 
AVG(prediction), 
    (CASE WHEN 
        (p.prediction) < 0 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS Z 
FROM rates.rates_cohort_predictions AS p 
GROUP BY 1,2 
ORDER BY p.cohort_name, DATEPART(Month, date)